Create a list with XPATH but not all nodes are available
I do have some weird XML I want to analyse:
<body>
<return>
  <items>
   <key>name</key>
   <value>A</value>
  </items>
  <items>
   <key>version</key>
   <value>1</value>
  </items>
</return>
<return>
  <items>
   <key>name</key>
   <value>B</value>
  </items>
</return>
</body>

As you can see: some "return" do have "items/value", some don't
I'd like an xpath expression where the output is something like
Name: A, Version: 1
Name: B, Version: n/a

I tried with both "map:merge" and ||
Yet I get cardinality error.
/*/return/items[key="name"]/value/string() ||/*/return/items[key="version"] 

Can I force /*/return/items[key="version"] to return "something" when the node is not found? So that I can get rid of the cardinality?
Maybe there's a totally different solution

Shouldn't need to use an if; just create a sequence of the version and a default value and use the first in the sequence.
Not sure what version of XPath you're using, but this should work for 3.0+. (If you're using 2.0, you might need to replace the concat operators (||) with concat().)
for $ret in //return return 'Name: ' || $ret/items[1]/value || ', Version: ' || ($ret/items[2]/value,'n/a')[1]


great.... tested, works like a charm... many thanks!

I found a partial solution:
using "if"...
that way I can extract the name separately and then the version separately and then merge the two lists in Excel
for $x in /body/return return (if ($x/items[key="version"]/value/string()) then $x/items[key="version"]/value/string() else '')
